# Lock but do not turn off display

Tags: ubuntu-gnome, lock

ubuntu locks with the shortcut and resumes succesfully (windows button + L)
but i do not want the screen to turn off. I want the screen to remain active and display the lockscreen.

running 17.10 on a laptop with gnome

Comment: Does [this solution](https://askubuntu.com/a/172525/18193) work for you?