# Ubuntu 18.04 disable lock screen display dimming / turn-off

Tags: gnome, 18.04, display, lock-screen, screensaver

**System:** Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS, Gnome Desktop (Xsession)

I would like to disable the lock screen turning off the screen immediately when pressing <kbd>super</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>.

The expected behavior is the lock screen being displayed and the screen staying on (showing the clock). Regardless of the lock screen being invoked by manually locking or the computer automatically locking.

*There is no setting in settings nor gnome-tweaks-tool nor dconf key for this.*

**Where can this be set?**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I prevent the blank screensaver when using keyboard shortcut to lock the computer?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/172447/how-do-i-prevent-the-blank-screensaver-when-using-keyboard-shortcut-to-lock-the) Check [this comment](https://askubuntu.com/questions/172447/how-do-i-prevent-the-blank-screensaver-when-using-keyboard-shortcut-to-lock-the#comment1738341_172525) first before trying the fix.