# Lock Screen - Screen Shield - Avoid 3 Up Scrolling Arrows. Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: lock-screen, screensaver

By following this excellent question and answer [How do I prevent the blank screensaver when using keyboard shortcut to lock the computer?](https://askubuntu.com/q/172447/739431) I just made my Lock Screen persistent.

However, I don't want to see those transient 3 upward scrolling arrows on the screen at 08:25 34th second & 40th second. above the date feild *Friday, December 14* in the animated gif.

How to achieve this?

[image]

Comment: Which arrows? I think they appear after a particular interval.

Comment: Those tell you to swipe up to unlock your screen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried to make the arrows invisible by hacking `/usr/share/gnome-shell/theme/ubuntu.css` file.

***Disclaimer: playing with shell files is very dangerous, small mistakes will stop access to GNOME desktop session. Only tty will work. I have several times reinstalled Ubuntu in such cases. although I have successfully achieved the required. Do this on your own risk.***

found this part,

```
.screen-shield-arrows Gjs_Arrow {
  color: white;
  width: 80px;
  height: 48px;
  -arrow-thickness: 12px;
  -arrow-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4); }
```

and made it to

```
.screen-shield-arrows Gjs_Arrow {
  color: white;
  width: 0px;
  height:0px;
  -arrow-thickness: 12px;
  -arrow-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4); }
```

hack: width & height fields made to 0px

[image]

Observe that at every 7th second, arrows should be visible..
now no more with the above edits in `/usr/share/gnome-shell/theme/ubuntu.css` file.