# Ubuntu 18.04 - Lock screen issue with GDM3

Tags: 18.04, gnome, gdm

I have recently upgraded a few of our Ubuntu machines to Ubuntu 18.04. I have managed to configure everything and everything seems to be working fine, apart from the lock screen.

It seems that if the computer is left idle for longer periods of time the lock screen will not accept the credentials any more and restart of gdm or the computer has to be done for it to work again.

I found [this bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-shell/+bug/1792843) which seems to describe the problem.

Can anyone advise me if there has been any work on this or if anyone has found a workaround?

Comment: may it help? just give a try https://askubuntu.com/a/172525/739431

Comment: It may help and I will give it a go. However I do wonder how would I change those shortcut settings through terminal. Any idea ? The problem I'm having is that I will have about 100 computers running ubuntu 18 so far I have had this problem with all of them so if this works I need to find a way of automating this. I can do so via deployment through puppet however for this I need to know how to edit default shortcuts and custom ones through terminal and not gui

Comment: ya, your point is rite, i suggest first you check this one manually. and i hope someone already asked this question keyboard shortcuts via command line. i will check the link and share you.

Comment: did you check the link?

Comment: Sorry not yet, bit busy with a lot of other config. I will get back to this and report in this thread if it worked and how I got it to work if I do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I have found a fix by adding below line to my sssd.conf

```
ad_gpo_map_interactive = +unity, +cron, +gdm3, +gdm
```

This seems to fix issues I had with GDM and also issues that I only just noticed where users couldn't run cron jobs

Answer (score 1):

According to [comment #10](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-shell/+bug/1792843/comments/10) by [nomike (michael-postmann)](https://launchpad.net/~michael-postmann) on the [bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-shell/+bug/1792843)

> When using sddm or lightdm I don't have this issues (though I have others).

Therefore, it seems that the only workaround is to use other Display Manager such as lightdm. To install lightdm, run:

```
sudo apt install lightdm
```

and follow on screen instructions.

Comment: Thanks, however I wanted to avoid using it as lightdm brings other issues into play such as constant crashes of display manager when using virtual desktops.